# Are there any additional benefits to using the default repository find methods over DQL in Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Doctrine has an entity/object repository class that define the following methods:

- `find($id)`
- `findAll()`
- `findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)`
- `findOneBy(array $criteria)`

I understand that these methods make it possible to easily obtain entities/objects from within the data-storage, however I am able to do the same thing with a (simple) DQL query.

Why would/should I use one over the other? And are there any additional benefits to using one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several advantages to using the `find*()` methods that I can think of.

- `find()` won't execute any queries if the requested entity is already in memory (managed by Unit of Work)
- they use SQL to fetch the entities, so there is no intermediate DQL query that needs to be parsed and converted to SQL
- the return values of these methods can be typehinted or annotated to get a better code-completion

Ideally you shouldn't be creating queries outside of entity repositories so they can be reused.